# Edit Signed request

Tags: canvas, canvas-app

Is there anyway I can edit what is put into the signed request that SalesForce returns in a canvas app? I would like to change the context.user fields. It gives us Id's rather than names and I would like to skip the step of querying for the names.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude items from a signed request but unfortunately there isn't an option to add or change items. Sounds like a good enhancement request you could file on [IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch)